# View the performance counters I have added to a Data Collector set after creation on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, performance-monitoring, perfmon, performance-counters

I have been working on creating a Data Collector Set to use to collect relevant performance information for an application my team is developing. I am using Performance Monitor on a Windows 2008 R2 server. However after I add the various performance counters to the Data Collector set through the properties window, I am unclear on how to revisit that list in order to add/remove values.

When I re-enter the same dialog by selecting the Data Collector Set in the navigation tree on the left side of the window and then right clicking the Data Collector I have just made and selecting Properties, Performance Counters Tab, Add, none of the counters I just added appear in the Added counters pane.

Is it possible to revisit the list of counters that have been added to a Data Collector Set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.
Most likely you've viewed Properties of your custom `DCS` (i.e. Data Collector Set) and not `Performance Counter` Properties.

Go to `Performance Monitor > Data Collector Sets > User Defined >` choose the one you set up, and on the right pane view Properties of the configured performance counters. Edit if necessary.

[image]